# Is the error "Duplicate variable definition" serious?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, duplicates

Just a question that I was asking to myself. 
Is it serious the error of duplicate variable definition ? What happen if we don't correct it ? (I had a project with , at least, 40 errors of duplicates variables. I correct it, but what happen if I don't ?)
It is just a curiosity question.

Thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean Errors or Warnings?

As far as I know it's not "Serious" because in bytecode variable is declared at the beginning of the function so it doesn't matter if you define it once or more times...